# html wont render from inside angular 2 component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm using a service to dynamically change the content in my header depending on the page I'm on, however when I put HTML in my component it doesn't render in the browser (see example below)

**home.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HeaderTitleService } from '../../services/headerTitle.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private headerTitleService: HeaderTitleService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.headerTitleService.setTitle(`
      We strive to create things
      <br> that are engaging, progressive
      <br> &amp; above all
      <span class="highlight">
      <em>innovative.</em>
      </span>
    `);
  }

}
```

**header.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HeaderTitleService } from '../../../services/headerTitle.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  title: any;

  constructor(
    private headerTitleService: HeaderTitleService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.headerTitleService.title.subscribe(updatedTitle => {
      this.title = updatedTitle;
    });
  }

}
```

**header.component.html**

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
```

so Im trying to set the title to be a string that has html tags in it that I want to be rendered but what happens is the whole thing comes out as a string instead of how it would look like it I had put it in my home.component.html.

Is there a way I can do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `[innerHtml]` property

```
<h1 [innerHtml]="title"></h1>
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8wosbh)